# SASL Authentication in Postfix

Tags: systemd

I am facing issue in starting saslauthd service. When I try to start saslauthd, below error is thrown:

```
[root@WQCogDev5 sysconfig]$ systemctl status saslauthd
â saslauthd.service - SASL authentication daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/saslauthd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-01-15 18:06:16 IST; 6s ago
  Process: 15621 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saslauthd -m $SOCKETDIR -a $MECH $FLAGS (code=exited, status=233/RUNTIME_DIRECTORY)
 Main PID: 15621 (code=exited, status=233/RUNTIME_DIRECTORY)

Jan 15 18:06:16 CTSC01024827401 systemd[1]: Started SASL authentication daemon..
Jan 15 18:06:16 CTSC01024827401 systemd[1]: Starting SASL authentication daemon....
Jan 15 18:06:16 CTSC01024827401 systemd[1]: saslauthd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=233/RUNTIME_DIRECTORY
Jan 15 18:06:16 CTSC01024827401 systemd[1]: Unit saslauthd.service entered failed state.
Jan 15 18:06:16 CTSC01024827401 systemd[1]: saslauthd.service failed.
[root@WQCogDev5 sysconfig]$ /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m $SOCKETDIR -a $MECH $FLAGS
saslauthd[15653] :set_run_path    : -m requires an absolute pathname
[root@WQCogDev5 sysconfig]$ vi saslauthd
[root@WQCogDev5 sysconfig]$ /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /run/saslauthd -a pam $FLAGS
saslauthd[15698] :main            : could not lock pid lock file: /run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid.lock
saslauthd[15698] :main            : fcntl: Resource temporarily unavailable
[root@WQCogDev5 sysconfig]$
```

I want to achieve sasl authentication in Postfix. Can you please help me in resolving the above error and make saslauthd up and running.

Comment: Do `/run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid.lock` and `/run/saslauthd/` exist?

Comment: No i dont find saslauthd.pid.lock file in /run/saslauthd/ path. But /run/saslauthd/ directory is present.

Comment: Are the permissions on this directory OK? Please edit your post with the output of `ls -ld /run/saslauthd`. Also add which distribution you are using.